# How to install CKeditor on MediaWiki

Tags: ckeditor, mediawiki

I've installed

-Wysiwyg 1.5.6_0 [B551+09.02.2017], CKEditor 4.5.9 (revision a35abfe), 
from https://github.com/Mediawiki-wysiwyg/WYSIWYG-CKeditor#short-installation-instructions

unto my server whose versions are

- http://mediawiki-22652-48932-215666.cloudwaysapps.com/index.php/Special:Version

I've followed the instructions by

- uploading the WYSIWYG folder into the extensions
- replaced WikiEditor/modules/ext.wikiEditor.toolbar.js in the appropriate folder
- Made sure the Preferences are correct
- added all code that starts with "#02.07.16-> ,#Enable WYSIWYG- extension, MW >= 1.25....." to my LocalSettings.php without any changes
- checked the versions and found that it was installed

When i want to edit the page, i dont see the WYSIWYG, is there something wrong with the installation steps?

Comment: You're running MW1.28 but README.md doesn't include 1.28 in the list of compatible versions.